# Creating fused ft and ct symbols from Old English

Tags: fonts, characters, ligatures, english

[image: students]

[image: product]

I am quoting an old document and would like to quote it properly. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Edit: This is the part of the document I need to be in the appropriate format.

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Number
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[psamsfonts]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsrefs, graphicx, float, centernot, amsmath, tabu, caption, booktabs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\raggedbottom

\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem*{example}{Ex}
\newtheorem*{postulate}{Postulate}
\newtheorem*{proposition}{Proposition}


\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\theoremstyle{acknowledgements}
\theoremstyle{addendum}
\newtheorem*{addendum}{The cardinal numbers $\mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathfrak{t}$}
\newtheorem*{acknowledgements}{Acknowledgements}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}
\newtheorem{solution}{Solution}

\begin{document}


\section*{Chapter 0}
"After the definitions we have given of \emph{nothing} and 
\emph{infinity}, the following rules taken from the writings of an 
eminent mathematician, it is prefumed, will not be thought
prepofterous; and in the higher branches of the mathematics they 
will be found of confiderable utility to ftudents" 
- \emph{Jared Mansfield, 1802 speaking to Emerson's Algebra}

\subsection{Emerson's Algebra}

\begin{enumerate}
\item If \emph{nothing} multiply any finite quantity, the product will be nothing.

\item If \emph{nothing} multiply an infinite quantity, the product is a finite quantity. Or a finite quantity is a mean proportional between nothing and infinity.

\item If a finite quantity be divided by nothing, the quotient is infinite,

\item If nothing be divided by nothing, the quotient is a finite quantity.

\item If a quantity be nothing and the index of its power nothing, that quantity is equal to unity ; or the infinitely fmall power of an infinitely fmall quantity is infinitley near 1.

\item Adding or fubtracting any finite quantities to or from an infinite quantity, makes no alteration, therefore,

\item In any equation where are fome quantities infinitely lefs than others ; they may be thrown out of the equation.

\item An infinite quantity may be confidered either as affirmative or negative.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please explain your question better! Which document class do you use? Do you have font(s) installed with the old ligatures? Which one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not an ft ligature but a [long s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s)-t ligature. The other one is a ct ligature. Not every font contains such symbols, and typically you have to use a system like OpenType (via XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX) to access them. Here an example using the Libertinus font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{libertinusserif-regular.otf}[Ligatures=Historic]
\begin{document}
ſtudents
products
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

It is quite typical that one needs `Ligatures=Historic` to activate things like the ct ligature, but you will have to check the documentation for your font to see what is appropriate. As for using this style within a longer text, you have to make on decision first: Should the same font but with different features be used for "normal" text and historic citations, or should different fonts be used? Here a simple example where the same font is used:

```
\documentclass[psamsfonts]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsrefs, graphicx, float, centernot, amsmath, tabu, caption, booktabs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}

\usepackage{libertinus}
\newcommand{\histligs}{\addfontfeatures{Ligatures=Historic}}

\begin{document}
{\histligs product ſtudent preſumed \textit{is different} from prefumed}

Some normal text with product and a formula

\begin{equation}
    E = mc^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

I am again using Libertinus, since that supports not only the necessary text features but also math. If you want the historic citations to stand out, you can switch fonts like this:

```
\documentclass[psamsfonts]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsrefs, graphicx, float, centernot, amsmath, tabu, caption, booktabs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\histligs}{libertinusserif-regular.otf}[%
  Ligatures = Historic,
  ItalicFont = libertinusserif-italic.otf]

\begin{document}
{\histligs product ſtudent preſumed \textit{is different} from prefumed}

Some normal text with product and a formula

\begin{equation}
    E = mc^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Of course, there are more pleasing font combinations than Latin Modern and Libertinus, but finding those is not at all trivial.

Note that all these documents have to be processed with an OpenType aware TeX engine (XeTeX or LuaTeX).

Comment: I am looking to combine what is used in this post with this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document/25251#25251

Comment: I am writing a math document, and wish to keep the air around the original quote.
The way I have currently written the quote in appears to the reader that I have typos as I simply replaced the s's with f's where was appropriate. I want to use this ligature and font in just one part of the paper, or two rather, where I am quoting these people. The current header of my document is: \documentclass[psamsfonts]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsrefs, graphicx, float, centernot, amsmath, tabu, caption, booktabs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}

Comment: I downloaded tex live and attempted to compile using non-pdf builds but wasn't able to successfully code in for the desired effects.

Comment: @JordanHess I am sorry, but I cannot follow your explanations. Can you post a minimal example document (minimal header, normal text, some math and quoted text), either as an edit to your question or as a new question?

Comment: okay. I edited the original question.

Comment: Another font with these ligatures that you could use this way is `\setmainfont[Ligatures=Rare]{Junicode}`, which is a font specifically created for medievalists. The font files can be installed either manually on your OS or via the `junicode` package (which doesn't seem to include a .sty file though).

Comment: @JordanHess Please see the updated answer for some possibilities.

Comment: Thank you @Ralf Stubner! I really appreciate your help on this one. And thanks doncherry for your input as well!. To any future users who find this page, note that you must compile using LuaLaTex or XeLaTeX as opposed to LuaTeX or XeTeX.